# Handling HTML in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I had a problem when I took out html files and imported them into excel.

This is the site i need to get information: https://www.kylc.com/stats/global/yearly_per_country/g_gdp/vnm.html

As you can see, in the GDP table I have a row named : 年份 separated from 2 lines

That's why after i exported the excel file it gave unexpected results

The result I want is that the first line in excel will only have : 年份 , GDP(美元), 占世界%

Sorry for my confusing explanation, I really don't know how to explain it in detail.

Here is my python code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

def get_html(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding  
        return r.text
    except:
        r = "fail"
        return r
    
def getGDP(ulist,html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    trs = soup.find_all('tr')    
    for tr in trs:
        list = []    
        for th in tr:  
            ts = th.string  
            if ts == '\n':
                continue
            list.append(ts)
        ulist.append(list)
        
def saveGDP(ulist):
        file_name = '21095010 胡碧玉 GDP.csv'
        with open(file_name,'w',errors='ignore',newline='') as f:
                f_csv = csv.writer(f)
                f_csv.writerows(ulist)
        
def main():  
        unifo=[]    
        url='https://www.kylc.com/stats/global/yearly_per_country/g_gdp/vnm.html'
        html=get_html(url)    
        getGDP(unifo,html)
        saveGDP(unifo)    

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pandas` scraping tables and cleaning of results in most cases is mutch easier - under the hood `beautifulsoup` is working for you.

In this case `read_html()` the table, drop the unwanted header level and filter out the rows containings ads:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://www.kylc.com/stats/global/yearly_per_country/g_gdp/vnm.html')[0].droplevel(0, axis=1)

df[~df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('ads')].to_csv('21095010 胡碧玉 GDP.csv', index=False)
```

---

###### Answering your question

You have to select your elements more specific e.g. with `css selectors`.

So first get the `thead` information from all `th` witout colspan, than collect the data from all `tr` in `tbody` that do not contains ads:

```
def getGDP(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    data = []
    data.append([th.text for th in soup.select('thead th:not([colspan])')])
    for row in soup.select('tbody tr:not(:-soup-contains("ads"))'):
        data.append(list(row.stripped_strings))
    return data
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

def get_html(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding  
        return r.text
    except:
        r = "fail"
        return r
    
def getGDP(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    data = []
    data.append([th.text for th in soup.select('thead th:not([colspan])')])
    for x in soup.select('tbody tr:not(:-soup-contains("ads"))'):
        data.append(list(x.stripped_strings))
    return data
        
def saveGDP(ulist):
        file_name = '21095010 胡碧玉 GDP.csv'
        print(ulist)
        with open(file_name,'w',errors='ignore', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f_csv = csv.writer(f)
            f_csv.writerows(ulist)
        
def main():  
        url='https://www.kylc.com/stats/global/yearly_per_country/g_gdp/vnm.html'
        html=get_html(url)    
        saveGDP(getGDP(html))    

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: sorry for my late response. i tried your way and problem solved.
about the duplicate post I closed it. Thanks for the reminder